Generic function return value not assignable when using mapped types
What is the error in this code:
  type Variants0 = {
    variant0: { v0: string };
    variant1: { v1: string };
  };

  const callAllVariants = <S extends { [P in keyof Variants0]:any }>(
    f: <V extends keyof S>(m: V) => S[V],
  ): { [V in keyof Variants0]: ReturnType<typeof f<V>> } => {
    return {
      variant0: f('variant0'),
      variant1: f('variant1'),
    };
  };

  const r0 = callAllVariants<Variants0>(<V extends keyof Variants0>(v: V) => {
    return {
      variant0: { v0: 'v0' },
      variant1: { v1: 'v1' },
    }[v];
  });

  type Variants1 = { [V in keyof Variants0]: Variants0[V] & { extra: number } };

  const r1 = callAllVariants<Variants1>(
    <V extends keyof Variants1>(vs: V): Variants1[V] => {
      const r = {
        variant0: { v0: 'v0', extra: 0 },
        variant1: { v1: 'v1', extra: 1 },
      }[vs];
      // Doesn't work:
      const r3: Variants0[V] & { extra: number } = r;
      const r2: Variants1[V] = r3;
      return r2;
      // Works:
      // return r;
    },
  );

The compile error is:
Type 'Variants0[V] & { extra: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Variants1[V]'.
  Type 'Variants0[V] & { extra: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ v0: string; } & { extra: number; } & { v1: string; }'.
    Type 'Variants0[V] & { extra: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ v0: string; }'

I don't understand why Variants0[V] & { extra: number } isn't the equivalent type of Variants1[V]
If I comment out the r2 and r3 lines and uncomment the return r then it compiles fine, but I don't understand what the issue is. This is a simplified version of some code where I am having a similar issue but can't easily get rid of the intermediate types.

What is { [P in keyof Variants0] }? Are you not using --noImplicitAny or is that a typo?

This is caused by ms/TS#30769 being extra vigilant about assignments to indexed accesses. I don't know exactly why TS doesn't see the input type as being of the proper type, but that's the general cause (and ms/TS#47109 plays around a lot with how to try to force TS to see equivalences). Personally I'd think you might want to file an issue with a true [mre] like this playground link and ask, and then report back here. Or I might do that. Thoughts?

not a typo, copied it straight out of some code that I was running, im not sure what options I have, but maybe? my intent there was just to constrain the keys and leave the value types to be inferred

@jcalz if you are willing to follow through with a report, then that would be useful.  I'm not sure I can spare the time at the moment, I'll likely have to come up with some workaround and move on...

You should write {[P in keyof Variants0]: any} then. In fact your example has a few errors unrelated to what you're asking about. I'll consider filing an issue if I can't find an existing one.

@jcalz as a workaround, do you by-chance know how I could change callAllVariants to accept any return value type, and then return an object with the types of the return values? I tried adding a new generic type parameter as a place holder for the return type, but getting "could be instantiated with an arbitrary type" errors

Use type assertions or something? It seems like this is a followup question (the question as asked is "what is the error" and "I don't understand", not "how do I work around it") so I'm not necessarily ready to delve into it in the comments.
